# How do I check if combination of elements of two lists exists in a third list?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I have a list of tuples which looks something like this

```
data = [("hyd", "ab", 10.99), ("del", "ab", 12.99), ("del", "cc", 10.19), ("cal", "dd", 4.99), ("hyd", "ee", 13.11), ("noi", "dd", 10.49), ("noi", "bb", 10.99),]
```

I have two other lists below

```
loc = ["noi", "del", "cal", "hyd"]

dealer = ["ee", "dd", "ab", "cc", "bb"]
```

Now for every element of `dealer`, I want a list of values for every corresponding elements of `loc`

So since there are 5 elements in `dealer` I would would five lists with values for each corresponding elements of `loc`.

Something like

For `ee`, it is going to check againt each element of `loc` list and find out from the data what value it contains for each element of `loc`

For `ee` `[None, None, None,  13.11]`

So we can see above `ee` checks against `noi`, finds nothing in `values` hence assigned None.Then it checks against `del`, finds nothing hence assigned None, then it checks against `cal`, finds nothing, assigned None but for `hyd` it finds 13.11 and hence assigned the value.

Similarly,
For `dd` `[10.49, None, 4.99, None]`
and so on...

How can I get five lists for the five elements of the dealer?

I tried doing something like this

```
temp_list = []
for i in dealer:
   print("i", i)
   for j in loc:
      print("j", j)
      for k in data:
         #print("k", k)
         if i in k and j in k:
            temp_list.append(k[2])
         else:
            temp_list.append(None)
```

But I don't get the expected output. How do I get the lists?

**Complete expected output**

```
ee [None, None, None, 13.11]
dd [10.49, None, 4.99, None]
ab [None, 12.99, None, 10.99]
cc [None, 10.99, None, None]
bb [10.99, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Please give us the complete expected output.

Comment: @timgeb added the expected output.

Comment: There's a mistake in the expected output for `'ab'`, see my answer.

Comment: I think the third line should be `[None, 12.99, None, 10.99]`?

Comment: @timgeb yes it will be `10.99` my bad!

Comment: also, is the expected output a list of lists or a dictionary?

Comment: @timgeb a list of lists is preferrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use better data structures!

Assuming no two elements of `data` can be equal in their first two elements, you can make your life easier by using the following dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> data = [("hyd", "ab", 10.99), ("del", "ab", 12.99), ("del", "cc", 10.19), ("cal", "dd", 4.99), ("hyd", "ee", 13.11), ("noi", "dd", 10.49), ("noi", "bb", 10.99),]
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> 
>>> for key, subkey, val in data:
...:    d[key][subkey] = val
...:    
>>> d
>>> 
defaultdict(dict,
            {'cal': {'dd': 4.99},
             'del': {'ab': 12.99, 'cc': 10.19},
             'hyd': {'ab': 10.99, 'ee': 13.11},
             'noi': {'bb': 10.99, 'dd': 10.49}})
```

... because now you can do:

```
>>> loc = ["noi", "del", "cal", "hyd"]
>>> dealer = ["ee", "dd", "ab", "cc", "bb"]
>>> 
>>> [[d[lo].get(deal) for lo in loc] for deal in dealer]
>>> 
[[None, None, None, 13.11],
 [10.49, None, 4.99, None],
 [None, 12.99, None, 10.99],
 [None, 10.19, None, None],
 [10.99, None, None, None]]
```

... or in case you want a `dict`:

```
>>> {deal:[d[lo].get(deal) for lo in loc] for deal in dealer}
>>> 
{'ab': [None, 12.99, None, 10.99],
 'bb': [10.99, None, None, None],
 'cc': [None, 10.19, None, None],
 'dd': [10.49, None, 4.99, None],
 'ee': [None, None, None, 13.11]}
```

Comment: hey does `d` represents data?

Comment: @SouvikRay `d` represents the data in `data` as a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a much more efficient way. Your solution is O(len(data) * len(dealers) * len(locations)). We can do in in O(len(data)) by iterating only once on data:

```
data = [("hyd", "ab", 10.99), ("del", "ab", 12.99), ("del", "cc", 10.19), ("cal", "dd", 4.99), ("hyd", "ee", 13.11), ("noi", "dd", 10.49), ("noi", "bb", 10.99),]
locations = ["noi", "del", "cal", "hyd"]
dealers = ["ee", "dd", "ab", "cc", "bb"]


out = {dealer: [None] * len(loc) for dealer in dealers} 
loc_index = {val: index for index, val in enumerate(locations)}

for location, dealer, amount in data:
    try:
        out[dealer][loc_index[location]] = amount
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        pass

print(out)
# {'ee': [None, None, None, 13.11], 'cc': [None, 10.19, None, None], 
# 'dd': [10.49, None, 4.99, None], 'ab': [None, 12.99, None, 10.99], 
# 'bb': [10.99, None, None, None]}
```